# Get A-Weighted Decibel value from signal with NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing, fft, naudio

I have a signal of float values representing audio.

Is it possible using NAudio to analyse this stream and return an A-Weighted decibel value?

Comment: If you want dB SPL then you can only do this if you have a way of calibrating your system to some reference SPL. Otherwise you can only get an arbitrary dB value.

Comment: Thank you Paul. arbitrary is acceptable for the purpose of this question. We have a means of calibration and have no issue generating a flat dB. The important part is that the dB value is A-Weighted and this is the sticking point.

Comment: OK - in that case it shouldn't be too hard - just apply an A-weight filter and then take a smoothed (low-pass-filtered) magnitude and convert to (arbitrary) dB. Unfortunately I don't know anything about [tag:naudio] so I'll have to leave it to someone more knowledgable to supply specific details.